# Is it ok to have a lot of jobs queries in Laravel query log?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, logging

Recently our Laravel query log became significantly larger. It was around ~50-100mb per day and after one day it increased to ~1-1.5gb.

There are a lot of queries to `jobs` table, like this

```
[05.08.2020 00:00:02] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574802, 1596571202]
[05.08.2020 00:00:05] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574805, 1596571205]
[05.08.2020 00:00:09] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574809, 1596571209]
[05.08.2020 00:00:12] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574812, 1596571212]
[05.08.2020 00:00:15] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574815, 1596571215]
[05.08.2020 00:00:18] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574818, 1596571218]
[05.08.2020 00:00:21] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574821, 1596571221]
[05.08.2020 00:00:25] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574825, 1596571225]
[05.08.2020 00:00:28] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574828, 1596571228]
[05.08.2020 00:00:31] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574831, 1596571231]
[05.08.2020 00:00:34] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574834, 1596571234]
[05.08.2020 00:00:37] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574837, 1596571237]
[05.08.2020 00:00:41] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574841, 1596571241]
[05.08.2020 00:00:44] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574844, 1596571244]
[05.08.2020 00:00:47] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574847, 1596571247]
[05.08.2020 00:00:50] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574850, 1596571250]
[05.08.2020 00:00:53] select * from `jobs` where `queue` = ? and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= ?) or (`reserved_at` <= ?)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update [default, 1596574853, 1596571253]
```

And they keep querying like that all day long.

How can I decrease this amount? Or is it OK to have that much `jobs` queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that seems normal if you have a backlog of jobs which take a few seconds to complete.

From the docs:

> When jobs are available on the queue, the worker will keep processing jobs with no delay in between them. However, the `sleep` option determines how long (in seconds) the worker will "sleep" if there are no new jobs available. While sleeping, the worker will not process any new jobs - the jobs will be processed after the worker wakes up again.
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts

So in your example, the queue worker has a backlog of jobs to process and is immediately fetching the next job after every completed job.